# How to enable latest TypeScript Language Service in VS Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code runs whatever TypeScript version that it's shipped with (currently v1.5). If I use some experimental compiler features such as AsyncFunctions then it will complain. Some other answers on SO [say](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29972103/450913) how to make VS Code to build project with a different version of TS, but I can't find an answer on how to make Language Service actually use the newer version.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380131/how-do-i-use-typescript-1-6-with-visual-studio-code-to-get-generators-support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://code.visualstudio.com/Updates#_languages-typescript-16-support

To enable 1.6 follow those directions.  Repeated here for brevity...

VS Code uses TypeScript 1.5 in the box. If you want to use a newer version of TypeScript, you can define the typescript.tsdk setting. The value of this setting is the absolute path to the lib folder of a TypeScript installation. This folder contains the file tsserver.js and the corresponding lib.*.d.ts files. Refer to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/07/27/introducing-typescript-nightlies.aspx) blog post for how to install the nightly builds of TypeScript.

These setting are experimental i.e. bad things could happen :)

Answer (score 5):

[Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56173789/7537658)

I'm on a mac and for some reason this was disabled

###### Extensions > @builtin typescript > Enable

Comment: Thanks this saved me. I tried everything else and this is the only answer that worked for me. Also on a mac.

Comment: Huge help! Ty for this. Didn't know about the @builtin flag either.